# Synaptics or libinput: which is being used?

Tags: synaptics, libinput

I do not know what libinput and synaptics exactly are or do, but it seems that at least one of them must be installed to use devices such as touchpad.

On my Xubuntu 22.04 these packages are installed:

- xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
- xserver-xorg-input-libinput
- libinput-bin
- libinput10

So it appears that both are installed, at least partially.

How can I know which is being used for handling my touchpad? And can I remove the other one safely?

Comment: You certainly do not want to remove `libinput`, as this needed by the system for all kinds of inout devices, see [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/).

Comment: @noisefloor, thanks. The introduction part of the documentation is not very clear in my opinion, maybe that's because it's written by someone like me who is not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out which user space layer is in use.

Run `xinput` and see the ID of your device.

Then run

```
xinput list-props <ID>
```

and you'll see. All modern Ubuntu releases use libinput by default.

Comment: Is this also the best way when Ubuntu runs in a Wayland session? I get a warning running xinput in Wayland.

Comment: I have noticed synaptics is used when it is installed. When I uninstall it, a slidebar labeled "sensitivity" disappears from the GUI tool of Xubuntu for touchpad settings, and my control over cursor movements decreases when I want to move it for a distance of a few pixels.

Comment: It depends on Xubuntu version. GUI is either based on synaptics or libinput